# Vs 2013 Only plain text

Tags: visual-studio-2013, editor, intellisense, code-completion

Recently i opened up visual studio 2013, for coding some c++. I opened it before, and i didn't do any reboot in between. Now i opened my project, en the text editor showed no colours at all, all gray text, en there was no code completion. I can still edit the code, and it still works, but there are no colours, no automatic braces, no code completion. For any project. I did not edit any settings, i just updated the program when it asked me.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i fixed my problem by running the setup, and choosing the repair option.
Everything is back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

Is the extension of the file .cpp or .h ? I guess Visual Studio does not recognize it as a C++ source-file, so you will get no syntax-highlighting.

Have you tried deleting the Intellisense-Database? This is the .sdf-file that is usually located in the same directory as the Solution (.sln) file. Exit Visual Studio, delete the .sdf-file and open the project again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Testing this tomorrow!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, i'll say again: it's program wide, so it's for all projects...